# Plotting Six Genres of Movies by Year

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am working on a project for school and I am having trouble extracting information from my dataset and plotting it. I am using the dataset "movies" and the package "ggplot2movies". My task is to filter six movie genres (Action, Comedy, Romance, Drama, Documentary, and Animation) ranging from the years 1990 to 2005, and plot the number of movies produced by year. Each genre should have "one curve", and all curves must be plotted in the same figure. It must include an appropriate legend and have different colors.

I already have some the code, but it not running as expected. I am obviously new to this and could use assistance. The code can be found here:

```
library(ggplot2movies)
data(movies)

filtered_movies <- movies %>% filter(year >= 1990 & year <= 2005, Action ==1, Comedy == 1, Animation == 1, Drama == 1, Documentary ==1, Romance == 1)

Genresix = tibble(Genre = c("Action", "Animation", "Comedy", "Drama",
"Documentary", "Romance"),
Movies1990 = c(filtered_movies$Action,
filtered_movies$Animation,
filtered_movies$Comedy,
filtered_movies$Drama,
filtered_movies$Documentary,
filtered_movies$Romance
))

ggplot(data = movies, mapping = aes(x = Genre, y = years)) +
geom_line(size = 5)+ geom_line(colour = "red")
plot <- ggplot(filtered_movies, aes(x = year, color = genre)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count", aes(group = genre)) +
  labs(title = "Number of Movies by Genre (1990-2005)",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Number of Movies") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Genre")

# Display the plot
print(plot)
```

I have an idea of what to do, but the specifics of how to translate my ideas into R, I am not sure. Feel free to peruse the "movies" dataset yourself. The Genre "Short" is NOT suppose to be included for the assignment.

I am trying to plot six movie genres (Action, Comedy, Romance, Documentary, Drama, and Animation) from the dataset "movies" using R. The graph must include an appropriate legend and different colors.
There should be one curve plotted for each genre and all curves must be in the same figure. I tried using ggplot, but something is missing. I expected a plot of each genre by year (1990 to 2005). It states:

```
Error in `tibble()`:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 6: Existing data.
• Size 0: Column `Movies1990`.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
Backtrace:
 1. tibble::tibble(...)
```

I am obviously a novice and could use some help.
The code can be found below:

```
library(ggplot2movies)
data(movies)

filtered_movies <- movies %>% filter(year >= 1990 & year <= 2005, Action ==1, Comedy == 1, Animation == 1, Drama == 1, Documentary ==1, Romance == 1)

Genresix = tibble(Genre = c("Action", "Animation", "Comedy", "Drama",
"Documentary", "Romance"),
Movies1990 = c(filtered_movies$Action,
filtered_movies$Animation,
filtered_movies$Comedy,
filtered_movies$Drama,
filtered_movies$Documentary,
filtered_movies$Romance
))

ggplot(data = movies, mapping = aes(x = Genre, y = years)) +
geom_line(size = 5)+ geom_line(colour = "red")
plot <- ggplot(filtered_movies, aes(x = year, color = genre)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count", aes(group = genre)) +
  labs(title = "Number of Movies by Genre (1990-2005)",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Number of Movies") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Genre")

# Display the plot
print(plot)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question's title so it won't be specific to your problem? I can't ven tell what language you're using.
Also you wrote most of the question twice

Comment: You would probably be better off aggregating the data first, to end up with a dataset that has years, number of movies and genre.  Then you can plot lines where x is years and y is number of movies where the color aesthetic is genre.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code. First, your `filter` statement will keep only films with a "1" in each of the six genre columns and apparently there is no film which meets this condition. Second, there are easier ways to stack multiple data frame columns, i.e. you could use `tidy::pivot_longer` to reshape your data, then `filter` for films which belong to one of the six genres.

After doing so your plotting code works fine:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggplot2movies)

filtered_movies <- movies %>%
  filter(
    year >= 1990 & year <= 2005,
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(c(
    Action, Comedy, Animation, 
    Drama, Documentary, Romance
  ), names_to = "genre") |> 
  filter(value == "1") |> 
  select(title, year, genre)

ggplot(filtered_movies, aes(x = year, color = genre)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count", aes(group = genre)) +
  labs(
    title = "Number of Movies by Genre (1990-2005)",
    x = "Year",
    y = "Number of Movies"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Genre")
```

[image]